# Code in the JsFiddle is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I have one query, for that I wanted to prepare a JSFiddle. But it's not working for a small click program. Which has just two lines of code.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <button onclick="javascript:launchdialog();">Click Me</button>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function launchdialog() {
    alert('test');
}
```

I didn't find anything wrong in just two lines of code.
Please have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g47qqzra/) - http://jsfiddle.net/g47qqzra/

Comment: Working after changing the file to `no wrap`. Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/g47qqzra/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the option to `No wrap` in head or body.

When you use `onload` or `onDomReady`, your code is wrapped inside another function that is invoked on `load` or `ready` event. So, your function is not accessible from outside of that function. And you'll get error

> ReferenceError: functionName is not defined

Making the function `no wrap` makes it **global**, can be accessed from anywhere.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/g47qqzra/1/)

[**Jsfiddle Doc**](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar)

Answer (score 4):

**onLoad**:

- This means wrap the code so it will run in `onLoad` window event. This runs when the entire page has loaded (such as images).

**onDomReady**:

- This means to wrap the code so it will run in `onDomReady` window event. This runs when the DOM has loaded.

**no wrap - in `<head>`**:

- This will place your JavaScript code in the `<head>` section

**no wrap - in `<body>`**:

- This will place your JavaScript code in the `<body>` section

I would like to note that more information can be found in [jsFiddle's documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html).

Your working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g47qqzra/6/)

Answer (score 1):

On the left set "`No wrap - in <head>`"

[Here is the updated JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/g47qqzra/2/)

Comment: @Tushar seems like you explained it already :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you script is not loaded and the function `launchdialog()` is not found when the page is loaded. If you place the script in head tag, it will be loaded before the page is loaded, hence solve your issue.
When you use 'onLoad' option script is loaded only after the document is loaded  i.e. in the end.
Just select "No wrap - in " on the left set