# Why does the background color not change in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, onfocus

I found this code from w3schools. There it works but when I run it in jsfiddle there is an issue.

```
<input type="text" onfocus="myFunction(this)">


function myFunction(x) {
    x.style.background = "yellow";
}
```

[Here is the code in jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/f11ppv4L)

Comment: check on the left menu that the javascript is not "onload" but "no wrap -in head" or something like that

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848850/code-in-the-jsfiddle-is-not-working/31848917#31848917

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/45h9przp/

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I didn't know that it was duplicated. How can I delete my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you dont need to include `jquery`.
- Add your script in `body` not `onLoad`.

[See the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f11ppv4L/2/)

**Edited**:Better if it would be added in `head`

Comment: better if it would be "head"

Answer (score 0):

Using `addEventListener` works for me.

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
    this.style.background = "yellow";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f11ppv4L/4/