# Object literal pattern OnClick Event in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp.net button that render as,

```
<button onclick="Person.Eat.rice();">Click me</button>
```

I am using Object Literal Pattern here,

```
var Person = Person || {};

Person.Eat = {
    rice: function() {
        console.log("Eating Rice");
    },
};
```

**Error**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Person is not defined

**Question**

Is there anyway I can use Object Literal Pattern in ASP.Net Button's onclick event like above ?

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ap8dn4nr/

Comment: You need to declare your JS code in the right place - https://jsfiddle.net/ap8dn4nr/1/. Note in the bar on the left, I placed your JS code in the `<head>` of the page. Putting it before the `</body>` would work too.

Comment: Works after setting option to `no wrap`. Check [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/fyhbjgyv/). For reference on how it works see [fiddle docs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar) or http://stackoverflow.com/a/31848917/2025923 or  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32925927/2025923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the script before using them in inline attribute event.