# Adding Border with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently working on my lab for my College COSC class. In the lab I should be able to click on a button and the buttons border should turn to "3px solid green"
This is what I currently have:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lab 10</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            div, p{
                width: 600px;
                background-color: lightgray;
            }
            .border_green{
                border: 3px solid green;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript>">
            $("#b1").click(function(){
                $("#b1").attr("Class",".border_green");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="b1" classname="button" type="button" value= "If this is clicked, a green solid border of three pixels will be created.">
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap your code in `ready`. **Code:** `$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#b1").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("border_green");
    });
});`

Comment: try this $("#b1").attr("Class","border_green");

Comment: This is what i'm using $("#b1").css("border","3px solid green");

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the dot symbol from the class name and wrap your script in the ready method as Tushar suggested
Here is the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/t0m4s0zy/2/)
Here is the updated script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b1").click(function(){
         $("#b1").attr("class","border_green");
    });
});
```

Comment: Will not work. the main problem is event is not bound. The code need to be wrapped in `ready` or moved to the bottom of `<body>`.

Comment: @Tushar It will work, please look at my demo

Comment: @Tushar It is not necessary to write the ready tag because the event will automatically be called when the button is pressed

Comment: Regarding fiddle demo see bottom of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925912/why-class-selector-is-not-created-on-click-action/32925927?s=1|5.2414#32925927) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31848917/2025923). And you'll understand why it works in fiddle.

Comment: Here's your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/t0m4s0zy/1/), the code is like OP.

Comment: Also, use `addClass` to add class on element, and `$(this)` to refer the element that is clicked, inside the handler.